# android - Pass class as parameter to access static variables

Tags: android, class, static-methods

I need to pass a class so I can access its static variables.
Example:

```
Class FirstClass
{
static int x = 1;
}
Class SecondClass
{
static int x = 2;
}
```

I have a method in another class (which will be used both by FirstClass and SecondClass), but it need to access the static variables, here's the pseudocode with the logic:

```
public static void process(Class anyClass){
    anyClass.x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to determine which class to access at runtime, and you have several classes with similarly named variables, you can use Class.forName() to return an instance of a class given the class name as a string.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)

```
public static void process(String className){
     classInstance = Class.forName(className);
}
```

You would also need to know the class type (so that you can declare or cast classInstance correctly).  The easiest way to do this would be to have all of our "anyClass" types inherit from a common super class.

```
class AnyClassType1 extends AnyClass
class AnyClassType2 extends AnyClass
```

Then cast or declare classInstance:

```
AnyClass classInstance;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the members of the Class using reflection:

```
Field f = anyClass.getDeclaredField("x");
int xValue = f.getInt(null);
```

Access to static fields via reflection is possible by passing `null` as the instance argument to `getInt()`.

We're using `getDeclaredField` because you wanted to access non-public field. The downside of this, is that it will throw an `InvalidFieldException` if that field does not exist to the class you're looking at, even if it **is** defined in a superclass. But, of course, had it been defined in a superclass, it will have had public or protected access, and `getField` would work just as well.

Comment: this looks good pal, unfortunately it's throwing a NoSuchFieldException though that static field does exist.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. Since the `getField` will only work for publicly accessible fields. You'd need to either set the fields to public (or protected, if the accessor is in the same class), or to use `getDeclaredField` instead.